# How to access a nested hashtable value in C#

Tags: c#

I have a C# program where I need to lookup data based on keys.
I am porting my Python code to C# and finding it difficult to implement the equivalent of nested Python dictionaries. After many attempts at using C# Dictionaries, I settled on Hashtable because it is loosely typed.

I am able to write to my nested Hashtable structure, and I can read from it if I iterate. But what I want to do is access specific data based on specific keys.

Here is the code I am using, which works:

```
        foreach (DictionaryEntry x in ParameterTypes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.Key + " -- ");
            foreach (DictionaryEntry y in x.Value as Hashtable)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(y.Key + ": " + y.Value);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }
```

It gives me this output (sample):

EVENT_PARAM_SCTP_SHUTDOWN_RESULT --
name: EVENT_PARAM_SCTP_SHUTDOWN_RESULT
usevalid: Yes
description: The results of a SCTP Shutdown
numberofbytes: 1
type: ENUM

EVENT_PARAM_ENBS1APID --
 
name: EVENT_PARAM_ENBS1APID
numberofbytes: 3
usevalid: Yes
description: eNB S1 AP ID
resolution: 1
type: UINT

However, this code below doesn't work:

```
Console.WriteLine(ParameterTypes["EVENT_PARAM_ENBS1APID"]["description"]);
```

What is the proper way to get data based on the key and nested key as I am attempting?

Comment: You should switch to `DIctionary<K, V>`

Comment: I spent the whole day trying to use Dictionaries and gave up, went to hashtable instead for the loose typing. My keys may vary, and the types of the values may vary, and in some cases I have a 3rd level of nesting which is not shown here for clarity.

Comment: That sounds like a bad idea.  You should rethink your design to be more type-safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code produces the output you seem to expect...

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestProject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Parameter entry for ParameterTypes collection.
    /// </summary>
    class ParameterEntry : Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        // this is just an subclassed Dictionary class
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Parameter types collection.
    /// </summary>
    class ParameterTypes : Dictionary<string, ParameterEntry>
    {
        // this class is a Dictionary that holds ParameterEntry objects

        /// <summary>
        /// Add the specified value using its name as the key.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name='value'>
        /// A parameter entry.
        /// </param>
        public void Add(ParameterEntry value)
        {
            string key = (string)value["name"];
            this.Add(key, value);
        }
    }

    class TestProject
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var entry1 = new ParameterEntry();
            entry1.Add("name", "EVENT_PARAM_SCTP_SHUTDOWN_RESULT");
            entry1.Add("usevalid", "Yes");
            entry1.Add("description", "The results of a SCTP Shutdown");
            entry1.Add("numberofbytes", 1);
            entry1.Add("type", "ENUM");

            var entry2 = new ParameterEntry();
            entry2.Add("name", "EVENT_PARAM_ENBS1APID");
            entry2.Add("numberofbytes", 3);
            entry2.Add("usevalid", "Yes");
            entry2.Add("description", "eNB S1 AP ID");
            entry2.Add("resolution", 1);
            entry2.Add("type", "UINT");

            var types = new ParameterTypes();
            types.Add(entry1);
            types.Add(entry2);

            Console.WriteLine(types["EVENT_PARAM_ENBS1APID"]["name"]);
            Console.WriteLine(types["EVENT_PARAM_ENBS1APID"]["numberofbytes"]);
            Console.WriteLine(types["EVENT_PARAM_ENBS1APID"]["usevalid"]);
            Console.WriteLine(types["EVENT_PARAM_ENBS1APID"]["description"]);
        }
    }
}
```

You can certainly nest a `Dictionary` within a `Dictionary` and you can use strings as the primary keys and nested keys and use an object as the final nested value. You can also subclass the typed `Dictionary<>` class as your own class to abstract the implementation and make the code easier to read and understand. Keep in mind that if you're coming from Python or any other loosely-typed language, you have to re-think how you're approaching the problem in terms of a strongly-typed language like C#.

Comment: This is brilliant, I love it. Seeing how a few lines of class definitions could do so much has really got me interested and motivated in adopting the new mindset. I incorporated the code and concept into my project and it works nicely, and the code is lean and clean. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the other responders that you should rethink this structure instead of trying to mimic PHP.  But if you want to stick with it, the reason your double indexing didn't work is because `ParameterTypes["EVENT_PARAM_ENBS1APID"]` returns an `object`, which has no [] operator.  You have to cast it as a Hashtable to index it again.

First of all, you'll probably want to use the `is` operator to determine whether a given node is indeed a nested hashtable.  If it is, you can go

```
((Hashtable) ParameterTypes["EVENT_PARAM_ENBS1APID"])["description"]
```

or

```
(ParameterTypes["EVENT_PARAM_ENBS1APID"] as Hashtable)["description"]
```

Comment: How do I cast it properly. What would be the syntax? I had tried but failed :(

Comment: Using the provided syntax, trying to assign the value to a string (to print to console) gives me an error "Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)". But when I put (string) in front ot gives me a blank result on the console.For example:
string result = (string)((Hashtable)ParameterTypes["EVENT_PARAM_ENBS1APID"])["description"];

Comment: @hacker101 I don't know why you're getting a blank result.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use generic Dictionary type Dictionary so you can store nested collections:

```
      Dictionary<string,object> ParameterTypes  = new Dictionary<string,object>();
    //Populate the parameterTypes here
     foreach (var x in ParameterTypes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x.Key + " -- ");
        foreach (var in x.Value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(y.Key + ": " + y.Value);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
    }
```

If you have already defined a Class you can use it for the value:

```
 Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,YourType>> or similar
```

Comment: See comment in response to SLaks. Dictionaries don't offer enough flexibility (strongly typed), I thought hashtable would be more straightforward (loosely typed). I also saw some stackexchange Q&A on using classes. It seems to be getting a bit deep for what appears a simple and common thing in Python or Perl, but maybe having a class "ParameterTypes" and creating a collection of it would be the solution. I was hoping for something simple (I'm not a professional programmer).

Comment: Then you may want to try dynamic types in c# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx

Comment: I tried that earlier, but must have gotten the syntax wrong. I'll try again, more carefully.